# Why is the EF 6.4 generated SQL faulty?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a query that look something like this.
The UserId is random letter string.
The searchCritera is model to search for.
searchCriteria.MainRoleValueList contains the Roles the search for(enum)

```
var criteria = DBContext.People.Include(w => w.Main).AsQueryable();

//A lot of code that doesnt affect this senario.

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.UserIdLike))
{
     criteria = criteria.Where(i => i.UserId.Contains(searchCriteria.UserIdLike));
}
if (searchCriteria.MainRoleValueList != null && searchCriteria.MainRoleValueList.Count > 0)
{
         var MainMembership = DBContext.MainMemberships.Where(p => searchCriteria.MainRoleValueList.Contains(p.MainRoleValue) && p.ValidTo == null).Join(criteria,
                        main => new { main.UserId, main.Main_Id }, current => new { current.UserId, current.Main_Id }, (main, current) => main);

var tmp = MainMembership.ToList(); //Added line to trigger communication with SQL server
}
```

The sql code that is generated is

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Main_Id] AS [Main_Id], 
    [Extent1].[MainRoleValue] AS [MainRoleValue], 
    [Extent1].[ValidFrom] AS [ValidFrom], 
    [Extent1].[ValidTo] AS [ValidTo]
    FROM  [dbo].[MainRoleMembership] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[UserId] = [Extent2].[UserId]) AND ([Extent1].[Main_Id] = [Extent2].[Main_Id])
    WHERE ([Extent1].[MainRoleValue] IN (300, 400, 200, 410)) AND ([Extent1].[ValidTo] IS NULL) AND (([Extent2].[FullName] LIKE '%rty12tt%' ESCAPE N'~') 
    OR ([Extent2].[UserId] LIKE '%rty12tt%' ESCAPE N'~')) AND 
    ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        WHERE 1 = 0
    ))
```

And it works EXCEPT for the last part

```
EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        WHERE 1 = 0
```

Why is this added? Since it removes the correct result that I want.
If I remove that part and run the query on an SQL server it I get the user that I want.
How should I rewrite my query so this is not included?

Added: Yes the two tables that have UserId dont have a foreign key for
UserId. That is a bad design in the system but nothing I can fix for the moment.

Added: Added a foreign key for UserId between the tables but it didnt help

Comment: From what I see this does come from what you consider "lot of code that doesn't affect this senario." EF6 always does this when it infers from model constraints + predicates that a predicate can only be false.

Comment: You where right.. there was an empty list that was added when it shouldent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added and compared against an empty list .. that why the

```
EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        WHERE 1 = 0
```

was added. Added a count check for the list and the problem disappeared